# Unexpected output from Perl Dumper

Tags: perl, data-dumper

I was trying to assign one hash to another when I came across this unexpected situation.

I was printing the dumper to validate if the hash is formed correctly.

The Data::Dumper does provide the expected output when I iterate though the hash but it show some unexpected result when I print the entire hash.

Please see the code snippet below. Any insight will be a great help.

```
my (@aBugs) = (111,222,333);
my $phBugsRec;
my $phProfiles;
$phProfiles->{profiles} = { 'profile1' => 'default1' };
```

Forming the final hash:

```
foreach my $pBugNo(@aBugs){
    $phBugsRec->{bugAttributes}{$pBugNo}{totalEffort} = 0;
    $phBugsRec->{bugAttributes}{$pBugNo}{profiles}    = $phProfiles->{profiles};
}
```

If I dump the entire hash, I am not getting the expected output:

```
print '<pre>'.Dumper($phBugsRec).'</pre>';
```

---

```
$VAR1 = {
    'bugAttributes' => {
        '333' => {
            'totalEffort' => 0,
            'profiles' => {
                'profile1' => 'default1'
            }
        },
        '111' => {
            'totalEffort' => 0,
            'profiles' => $VAR1->{'bugAttributes'}{'333'}{'profiles'}
        },
        '222' => {
            'totalEffort' => 0,
            'profiles' => $VAR1->{'bugAttributes'}{'333'}{'profiles'}
        }
    }
};
```

But when I iterate over the hash, I get the expected output

```
foreach (sort keys $phBugsRec->{bugAttributes}){
    print '<pre>'.$_.':'.Dumper($phBugsRec->{bugAttributes}{$_}).'</pre>';
}
```

---

```
111:$VAR1 = {
  'totalEffort' => 0,
  'profiles' => {
    'profile1' => 'default1'
  }
};
222:$VAR1 = {
  'totalEffort' => 0,
  'profiles' => {
    'profile1' => 'default1'
  }
};
333:$VAR1 = {
  'totalEffort' => 0,
  'profiles' => {
    'profile1' => 'default1'
  }
};
```

Comment: Which part is unexpected?  Data::Dumper correctly identifies that there are multiple references to the same hash reference, and helpfully shows it.

Comment: @tripleee : I understand that Dumper is showing multiple references to the same reference.What I was expecting to see is full details of the hash of hash instead of the reference.Maybe my understanding of the output was slightly misplaced.Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I am writing a longish explanation...

Comment: @AbhiNickz please do not use inline code formatting to highlight arbitrary words just because they look technical. Important terms or names can be emphasized using _italic_. Variable names, function names and other obvious pieces of code should be marked as `code`. Names of modules are generally just written without formatting here on the Perl tag on SO, like Data::Dumper.  I've reversed your edit because it didn't improve the post.

Comment: Okay, Got it, but when i only changed the formatting in code, It displayed the error for minimum character change requirement so that's why I highlighted arbitrary words.

Comment: @AbhiNickz that's because your edit was too minor. Editing is useful, but you should always try to make the post better. Improve as much as you can, but don't just change stuff around. The [revision history is public](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38069913/revisions). Everyone can see what you did. You can read about the [later edit privilege at 2k rep] (http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) and about [editing in general](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). There are also various discussions on meta. [This one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253326/1331451) is nicely broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [tripleee says in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069913/unexpected-output-from-perl-dumper#comment63578178_38069913), this is not wrong. I agree it might be unexpected. It happens because you are using the same reference several times in a data structure. It's due to how Perl's references work.

**A short overview of references in Perl**

References are explained in [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) and [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html).

As soon as you have a data structure with more than one level in Perl, all levels after the first level are stored as references. The `->` operator is used to dereference them. Perls turns them back into hashes or arrays. You are basically traversing a data structure if you say `$foo->{bar}->{baz}` to get to the inner value.

If you set `$foo->{bar}->{baz} = 123` directly, Perl will create all those references for you automagically. But you can also make references yourself.

```
my @numbers = (42, 23, 1337);
my $ref = \@numbers;

print Dumper $ref;

__END__
$VAR1 = [ 42, 23, 1337 ]
```

This is a single reference to that array. If you use it more than once in the same data structure, it will show that.

```
my $hash = { 
    foo => $ref, 
    bar => $ref,
};

__END__

$VAR1 = {
      'foo' => [
                 42,
                 23,
                 1337
               ],
      'bar' => $VAR1->{'foo'}
};
```

Looks the same as your example, right? Let's try something else. If you print a reference in scalar context, Perl will tell you its address.

```
print "$ref";

__END__
ARRAY(0x25df7b0)
```

We've all seen that, and we've all thought *something is seriously wrong* when we first saw it. Let's go back to our `$hash` from above.

```
say $hash->{foo};
say $hash->{bar};

__END__
ARRAY(0x16257b0)
ARRAY(0x16257b0)
```

As you can see, it's the same address, because it's the same data structure.

**Other Perl serializers**

This is what your data structure looks with [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump).

```
do {
  my $a = {
    bugAttributes => {
      111 => { profiles => { profile1 => "default1" }, totalEffort => 0 },
      222 => { profiles => 'fix', totalEffort => 0 },
      333 => { profiles => 'fix', totalEffort => 0 },
    },
  };
  $a->{bugAttributes}{222}{profiles} = $a->{bugAttributes}{111}{profiles};
  $a->{bugAttributes}{333}{profiles} = $a->{bugAttributes}{111}{profiles};
  $a;
}
1
```

[Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) is meant for creating output that is both human readable and can be put back into Perl. It's a bit more concise than [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper). You can see that it also shows the values that are used more than once in your data structure.

And this is what [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) does to it.

```
\ {
    bugAttributes   {
        111   {
            profiles      {
                profile1   "default1"
            },
            totalEffort   0
        },
        222   {
            profiles      var{bugAttributes}{111}{profiles},
            totalEffort   0
        },
        333   {
            profiles      var{bugAttributes}{111}{profiles},
            totalEffort   0
        }
    }
}
```

[Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) is meant for human consumption only. You cannot run this as code, but instead it's meant to be easily readable. Again, it also shows that stuff is reused inside of the data structure.

The conclusion from all of this is that those serializers do that because it is not easy to show that something is reused. Not even when you say it in Perl.

**Why you can't see the whole data structure**

If Perl would omit the fact that there are parts of the data structure that have been reused, the serialization would not be reversible. The result of reading it back in would be something else. That's of course not what you would do.

**Serialization without reusing**

To show that your data is in fact not lost and this is really just a way to show (and port) that things are reused inside of the data structure, I have converted it to JSON using the [JSON module](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON), which is a portable format that can be used with Perl, but that *is not Perl*.

```
use JSON 'encode_json';
say JSON->new->pretty->encode( $phBugsRec);
```

Here is the result. It looks more like what you expected.

```
{
   "bugAttributes" : {
      "333" : {
         "profiles" : {
            "profile1" : "default1"
         },
         "totalEffort" : 0
      },
      "111" : {
         "totalEffort" : 0,
         "profiles" : {
            "profile1" : "default1"
         }
      },
      "222" : {
         "profiles" : {
            "profile1" : "default1"
         },
         "totalEffort" : 0
      }
   }
}
```

That's because JSON is meant to be a portable format. It's for moving data around. There is [an agreement on what it can contain](http://www.json.org/), and reusing data ist not part of that. Not every language that implements reading and writing JSON supports reuse of partial data structures<sup>1</sup>.

It would also just be printed twice if we would convert to YAML or XML.

<sup>1) I don't have proof for that, but it gets the point accross</sup>

Comment: Very nice explanation. But if you set `$Data::Dumper::Deepcopy=1` then Data::Dumper will also avoid the references and print the real data twice.

Comment: Really exhaustive and wonderful explanation.Thanks for the clarification and the effort.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$Data::Dumper::Deepcopy = 1;
print Dumper($phBugsRec);
```

From the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html#Configuration-Variables-or-Methods):

> - $Data::Dumper::Deepcopy or $OBJ->Deepcopy([NEWVAL])
>
>   Can be set to a boolean value to enable deep copies of structures. Cross-referencing will then only be done when absolutely essential (i.e., to break reference cycles). Default is 0.

Output is then:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'bugAttributes' => {
       '222' => {
          'totalEffort' => 0,
          'profiles' => {
                          'profile1' => 'default1'
                        }
                },
       '333' => {
          'profiles' => {
                          'profile1' => 'default1'
                        },
          'totalEffort' => 0
                },
       '111' => {
          'profiles' => {
                          'profile1' => 'default1'
                        },
          'totalEffort' => 0
                }
     }
};
```

Comment: I gave up using Data::Dumper about two years ago. Nowadays I only use Data::Printer for debugging, and I avoid using Data::Dumper for sharing data as well. That's what JSON and co are for. Or Sereal, or Freeze/Thaw. Anyway, nice find. :)

Comment: Oh. Well. I think in Cluj it's more likely you get your blood sucked out by Dracula. Next year's German Perl Workshop it is, then. Probably in Hamburg.